# Effects of Polyjuice Potion on the Pregnant

Tags: harry-potter

Some friends and I were swapping hypothetical scenarios regarding the Potter universe. Polyjuice potion, of course, brought up a number of interesting questions, but perhaps the most unsettling was what the effect might be if, say, a 9-months-pregnant witch consumed Polyjuice Potion made with the hair of an adult male. What would happen - would she successfully transform, with the infant being absorbed into her body and incorporated as part of the transformation? Or would the child remain unchanged within the new male body, as it is a separate entity? Or - the most horrifying possibility - would the infant ALSO transform into a second copy of the adult male, as it is directly connected to the mother's bloodstream, thereby certainly killing its own mother and likely itself in the process?

Cheers.